# Installing Script in Atom

Tags: python, command-line, installation, atom-editor

I struggle with a very basic problem in the Atom editor. I simply want to run a python file but am unable to just open a command line or console. In other forums I read, I need to install Script. I tried to do it in Packages -> Settings View. But if I type 'script' in the install packages field, only this response appears: Searching for “script” failed.Show output…

How can I make Atom to find this packages?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

- press ctrl+, to open your preferences
- go to install
- search for script
- press install

Comment: This is not the issue here. What do you do if install can't find script as a package?

Answer (score 0):

Given that `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom\bin` is in your `PATH`, you can type the following command in a terminal:

```
$ apm install script
```